# Duda bucle for y metodo remove() de listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Tengo una duda, de muy novato con el bucle `for`. El codigo es este:

```
lista = [29, 24, 23, 17, 16, 12, 5, -5, -12]
for i in lista:
    if i%2!=0:
        lista.remove(i)   

print(lista)
```

Me devuelve:

```
[24, 17, 16, 12, -5, -12]
```

La idea es quitar los números impares de esta lista. Si mal no entiendo, el problema que tengo es que cuando vienen 2 impares seguidos, al remover el primero, el siguiente pasa al indice del anterior y no lo contempla, por eso el 17 y el -5 siguen estando.

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo!

Comment: No soy experto en Python pero cuando tengo que eliminar elementos de un arreglo, lo recorro desde el final hacia el principio, así los elementos eliminados no alteran la posición de los elementos que faltan por recorrer.

Answer (score 2):

### ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

El problema es que con `remove()`, se está modificando la lista en cuestión. Por lo tanto los valores no van a ser los mismos en cada ciclo. La variable temporal que del ciclo va a tomar los valores de cada elemento en el iterable, significa que la iteración va a seguir por el siguiente elemento y va a dejar ciertos valores atrás.

```
for i in lista:
    print(i)
    if i % 2 != 0:
        lista.remove(i)
```

Con este ciclo se puede visualizar que valores toma i, por cada iteración. En pantalla se obtiene

```
29
23
16
12
5
-12
```

Como se puede, nunca se evalúan los valores `24, 27 y -5`, se quedan en la lista sin importar si se cumple la condición o no.

### ¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Lo más práctico es clonar la lista a una lista auxiliar, e iterar sobre esta lista auxiliar. Para no afectar los valores que toma la variable temporal:

```
lista = [29, 24, 23, 17, 16, 12, 5, -5, -12]
lista_aux = lista[:]

for elemento in lista_aux:
    if elemento % 2 != 0:
        lista.remove(elemento)
```

Aquí lo que pasa es que a `lista_aux`, se asignan todos los valores de lista. El slice `[:]` se refiere a todos los elementos de principio a fin del iterable.

Este pedazo de código mostraría con `print(lista)`:

```
[24, 16, 12, -12]
```

Si te molesta el hecho de haber creado otra lista entera solo para esto, después del final del ciclo se puede borrar a `lista_aux`:

```
del lista_aux
```

### ¿Por qué se debe de copiar un a lista con un slice de lista?

Veamos que pasa cuando se realiza una sentencia como

```
lista = [8,3,45,6]
lista_copia = lista
```

Se le está asignando el **valor** de `lista` a `lista_copia`. Lo primero que nos puede alarmar, es a la hora de verificar si son el mismo elemento:

```
print(lista is lista_copia)
```

muestra

```
True
```

Si intentamos modificar los valores de una, se modificará también la otra. Debido a que son **el mismo objeto**

```
lista.pop()
print(lista_copia)
```

muestra

```
[8, 3, 45]
```

Aquí se puede ver que se elimina el último elemento de `lista`, y esto también a afecta  a `lista_copia`.

*Y... ¿Esto por qué pasa?*

El truco está en el operador `=`, este es un operador de asignación. Se le asigna el valor de la derecha a la  variable de la izquierda. Por lo tanto no hay que asignarle el valor de `lista` a `lista_copia`, hay que asignarle a `lista_copia` cada uno de los elemento de `lista`

```
lista = [8,3,45,6]
lista_copia = lista[:]
```

Esta vez `print(lista is lista_copia)` devolverá `False`.

Espero te haya servido de algo.

Answer (score 2):

***Solución alternativa sin recurrir a copias de lista (listas auxiliares)***

Para eliminar elementos de una lista y evitar el error de cambio de indice, el código debe recorrer la lista al revés. Para esto, nos valemos de range() y len() de la siguiente forma:

```
lista=[29,24,23,17,16,12,5,-5,-12]
for i in range(len(lista)-1,-1,-1):
    if lista[i]%2!=0:
        lista.remove(lista[i])
print(lista)

outpot: [24, 16, 12, -12]
```

Empleando el tipo range(m,n,p) con tres argumentos, creamos una lista de números enteros que va desde m hasta n-1, aumentando o disminuyendo sus valores en p.

Ahora bien, aplicado a este problema nos sirve para definir la variable **i** que viene a ser el indice del elemento de la lista que queremos evaluar, donde **m** es el indice del ultimo elemento de la lista, dado por la cantidad de sus elementos menos uno "len(lista)-1", mientras que **n** es el indice del primer elemento de la lista, dado por 0-1=-1.

Nótese que p es el valor que determina en cuanto disminuye **i**.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas eliminando cosas de la lista sobre la cual estas iterando.

Lo mejor seria que trabajes con una lista auxiliar

Edit: para que veas lo que sucede mete un `print(i)` dentro del ciclo

Mira hago 1 paso y fijate lo que sucede

```
>>> lista = [29, 24, 23, 17, 16, 12, 5, -5, -12]
>>> lista
[29, 24, 23, 17, 16, 12, 5, -5, -12]
>>> i = iter(lista)
>>> next(i)
29
>>> lista.remove(29)
>>> lista
[24, 23, 17, 16, 12, 5, -5, -12]
>>> next(i)
23
>>>
```

Al borrar el 29 y ver el siguiente me devuelve 23, y no el 24 como esperaba

Comment: Si, he modificado y he añadido una lista auxiliar como bien me decias, añadiendole los pares solo. 
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @JavierGuerreroHuete por favor sigue las indicaciones en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers 
Por favor no añadas un comentario a tu pregunta diciendo “Gracias”. Los comentarios fueron diseñados para pedir clarificaciones, dejar críticas constructivas o añadir información adicional; no para socializar. Si quieres decir “gracias”, vota a favor o acepta la respuesta de ese usuario.